# asp.net mvc 4 -- is it valid to convert an empty list to a paged list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime-error, model-binding

I am working on an MVC program.

I have a list that is default:

```
List<T1> ourT1List = new List<Models.T1>();
```

Under certain logic the list itself is empty.

Can one still convert it to a paged list and return it?

```
       int pageSize = 1; 
       int pageNumber = 1; 

       var ourPagedList = ourT1List.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

The compiler *allows* it, but there is a run-time error:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

**This is a very specific situation, not just a general question about the above error.**  {This is in *response* to possible duplicate with answer.  }

It appears, but is not certain, that the error springs form the above code.

NOTE:  I **cannot** run the debugger in my environment [403 forbidden error], I have to 'publish' to iis, and work from any error messages.

Comment: That ToPagedList isn't runtime binding. I think something else on your page is failing to render.

Comment: @bommelding :  Yes that appears to be correct.  Please 'promote' your comment to an answer, and I will accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Anyone else have an answer, please?